# Is returning an iterator of private List (in class) considered bad practice?

Tags: java, oop, iterator

Suppose I have two classes: Animal and Zoo, which has private List containing instances of Animal.

Reason why I want to return iterator is to avoid defining setters and getters and removal methods.

Does that break encapsulation?

```
class Zoo{
    private List<Animal> animalList;
    public Zoo(){
        animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    }
    public void addAnimal(Animal animal){
        animalList.add(animal);
    }
    public Iterator<Animal> iterator(){
        return animalList.iterator();
    }
}

class Animal{
    private String name;
    private double weight, height;

    Animal(String name, double weight, double height){
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's ok for readonly operations. but, Iterator has a remove method too. You better disable that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is extremely uncommon to use Iterator outside an Iterable interface.
I'd advise against such practice.

I think this would be better:

```
public Iterable<Animal> animals(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableList( animalList );
}

for(Animal a : zoo.animals()) {
    //do something
}
```

I'm against having `Zoo implements Iterable<Animal>`; don't introduce unnecessary type relations.

In Java 8, a more preferred practice is probably to use Stream instead of Iterable

```
public Stream<Animal> animals(){
    return animalList.stream();
}

zoo.animals().forEach( ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Although there are situations when returning an iterator would be acceptable, in this particular case the `iterator()` method breaks encapsulation, because the class provides a method to mutate `animalList`.

As the result, the code that obtains an iterator, and mixes up iterations with calls to `addAnimal` would cause an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's break encapsulation.  Iterator of ArrayList has `remove()` method.

```
    Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
    // .....
    for (Iterator<Animal> i = zoo.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        i.remove();
    }
```

It is better to offer returning unmodifiable list.

```
    public List<Animal> animalList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(animalList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Reason why I want to return iterator is to avoid defining setters and getters and removal methods.

There is no good reason why you should not be adding these methods to your class. Your code definitely breaks encapsulation but we will come to that later. For now, it's safe to say that `Zoo` breaks a good OO design rule known as `Tell Don't Ask`.

With your current implementation, the client code will look like this :

```
zoo.iterator().remove();
zoo.iterator().next().getName();
```

The above code is really not readable. What would be ideal is to have something like this :

```
zoo.removeLastAnimal();
zoo.getNextAnimalName();
```

The `Zoo` class could be modified as follows :

```
class Zoo{
    private List<Animal> animalList;
    Iterator<Animal> iterator;

    public Zoo(){
        animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        iterator = animalList.iterator();

    }

    public void removeLastAnimal() {
        try {
           iterator.remove();
        } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }      

    public String getNextAnimalName() {
       if(iterator.hasNext()) {
          return iterator.next().getName();
       }
    }  
}
```

This way, you will hide implementation details from the outside world. You will prevent client code from making mistakes while using your code. You will be able to handle exception cases instead of asking the client code to handle them. This is what you get with good `encapsulation`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your class iterable:

```
public class Zoo implements Iterable<Animal> {

    ...

    public Iterator<Animal> iterator() {
        return animalList.iterator();
    }
}
```

Then you can just do something like this:

```
for (Animal a : zoo) {
    ...
}
```

If you return the iterator, you'd have to do it like this:

```
for (Animal a : zoo.iterator()) {
    ...
}
```

Which is sorta redundant.

---

You could also write your own iterator to prevent the user from calling `iterator.remove()` and modifying your list:

```
public class ReadOnlyAnimalIterator implements Iterator<Animal> {

    private Iterator iter;

    public ReadOnlyIterator(List<Animal> list) {
        this.iter = list.iterator();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iter.hasNext();
    }

    public Animal next() {
        return iter.next();
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then in the `iterator()` method:

```
return new ReadOnlyAnimalIterator(list);
```

---

So my answer to that question is that it would be better practice to make your zoo iterable, possibly overriding `Iterator` if you want to make it read only.

Comment: What if a Zoo also contains humans? As workers of course, not as exhibits. It's better to design it as `for(Animal a : zoo.animals())` and `for(Worker w : zoo.workers())`

Comment: @bayou.io True, in that case iterating over the zoo would iterate over a parent class (`Entity`?), and you could have methods to get iterators for specific lists?